# How to change the color of string

Tags: java, android

I am making an application in which i am using strings to diaplay some text on screen.But i want to change the color of the string to red.I don't know how to change the color of string to red.Please tell me how to do it.This is the string:

```
strRightAnswer = "Right Answers:" + "  " + String.valueOf(nRightAnswers);
```

Comment: check this link itwil help u http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1421

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the Color of the Text in TextView. Not the String color. It is not valid.

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

or Change your String to Html like this,

```
String s=  "<font color=#00aeef>"+"Right Answers:" + "  " + String.valueOf(nRightAnswers)+"</font>";
```

and

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

And find the color code for red and replace it with, `color=#00aeef` for the color you want, say red.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color is not the entire string, read about [spannablestring](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Create file res/drawable/text_color.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

**Then use @drawable/text_color from xml (or R.drawable.text_color from code) as text color for your list view items.**